# Two inner joins return empty result

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 very simple tables, `users`, `projects` and `starred_projects`.

`starred_projects` connects the other 2 other tables by having a user id and a project id.

```sql
CREATE TABLE projects
(
    project_id integer,
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    creator_id integer,
)

CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id integer,
    username character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE starred_projects
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    project_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

For a given user (e.g. "foo") I would like to display all projects he `starred`. Is an `INNER JOIN` the correct way to go here? When I do so, my result is always empty. As far as I remember from university, I would need two of them, as in:

```
SELECT
   p.name, u.username // display the name of the project and the user who created it
FROM
   projects p
INNER JOIN
   starred s
ON
   p.creator_id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN
   users u
ON
   u.user_id = p.creator_id
WHERE
   u.username = 'foo'; // display all starred projects of user foo
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Your code looks quite reasonable.

Comment: Sidenote: with postgres you're generally better off using the `TEXT` type rather than varchar - see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This

Comment: I think your JOIN is incorrect. Why do you have a `starred_projects` table is you aren't using it correctly. `projects` to `starred_projects` should be joined by `project_id`. `users` should join to `starred_projects` by `user_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users aren't necessarily creators.

A more correct way would be:

```
SELECT
   p.name, u.username // display the name of the project and the user who created it
FROM
   projects p
INNER JOIN
   starred s
ON
   p.project_id = s.project_id
INNER JOIN
   users u
ON
   u.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE
   u.username = 'foo';
```

In other words, the creator of the project is not necessarily the only user. So you use starred to figure out which users are starred in what projects. So you match **starred.user_id** with **user.user_id** and you match **starred.project_id** with **project.project_id**.

Users with **users**, and projects with **projects**.

Answer (score 2):

You have your table name as starred_projects yet in your INNER JOIN you quote it as just starred.  Is that correct?

I can't see anything else wrong with your code, are you able to provide examples of the data in each table?

Comment: This answer should really be a comment as you are requesting more information, not actually providing an answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Note that the contributor doesn’t yet have enough reputation to post it as a comment. (Though it still shouldn’t be posted as an answer, obviously.)